# Problem with intent while making a Discord BOT

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am a beginner in programming and I wanted to try to make a Discord BOT. I followed a video, but I am having some problem with what I am supposed to put in intent. If you have any idea let me know. It might be a basic problem tho.
The beginning of my code:
[image]

Comment: There is a typo in your code. It should be a comma (`,`), not a dot (`.`).

Comment: Please include your code as a codeblock, not a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Your problem was caused by a typo, you have to use `,` instead of `.` to list your client intents:

```js
let Client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["FLAGS", "GUILDS"]})
```